# Context menu did not fire for composite list item in listview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-contextmenu

I am developing a todo app. In this app, a todo item is added as a list item to a list view. Each list item (corresponds to each todo item) has relative layout with multiple view elements. I have registered a context menu for this listview. But the problem is that when I long press the list item, it is not fired. Following are the code blocks. Please help..

The list Activity (List view showing the todo items):

public class ToDoManagerActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private static final int ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST = 0;
private static final String FILE_NAME = "myToDos.txt";
private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

// IDs for menu items
private static final int MENU_DELETE = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int MENU_DUMP = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private static final int MENU_ADD = Menu.FIRST + 2;

ToDoListAdapter mAdapter;
TextView footerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a new TodoListAdapter for this ListActivity's ListView
    mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());


    // TODO - Attach the adapter to this ListActivity's ListView
    getListView().setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // register for context menu
    registerForContextMenu(getCurrentFocus());

}



@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater contextMenu = getMenuInflater();
    contextMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_context, menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Delete all");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DUMP, Menu.NONE, "Dump to log");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ADD, Menu.NONE, "Add ToDo");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_DELETE:
        mAdapter.clear();
        return true;
    case MENU_DUMP:
        dump();
        return true;
    case MENU_ADD:
        Intent mAddToDo = new Intent(ToDoManagerActivity.this,
                AddToDoActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(mAddToDo, ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

}}

The layout for list item is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleView"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/StatusLabel"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/statusCheckBox"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="@string/done_string" >
</TextView>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/statusCheckBox"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/StatusLabel" >
</CheckBox>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PriorityLabel"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/statusCheckBox"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/StatusLabel"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/priorityView"
    android:text="@string/priority_string" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/priorityView"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/statusCheckBox"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/StatusLabel" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DateLabel"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/statusCheckBox"
    android:text="@string/date_string" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dateView"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/DateLabel"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/DateLabel" >
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Context Menu xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/rajit_me"
    android:title="Rajit"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/mou_me"
    android:title="Mou"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/suha_me"
    android:title="Suha"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/samah_me"
    android:title="samah"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem: Just add the following two attributes to the checklist view in the list item:

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/statusCheckBox"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/StatusLabel" 

<!-- add these two attributes to disable the focus of the check box -->
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
>
</CheckBox>
```